# Localhost refused to connect error VIsual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm having trouble establishing a connection to a localhost port on my local machine. It starts of with the url as http://localhost:/portnumnber and then it changes to just http://localhost. I have tried to delete the (.vs) file and it didn't work. I haven't seen any other fixes that might work any response is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the forward slash from the URL.

Use "http://localhost:port" OR "http://127.0.0.1:port" instead of "http://localhost:/portnumnber"

Comment: Isn't there a command of some sort that I can use to reset all the connections to the localhost because the real problem is that the port number is removed from the url when ever I try to access it but I can access some other projects but I cant access the specific one

Answer (score 0):

Try "http://localhost:/portnumnber" is wrong...
Should be "http://localhost:portnumnber" without "/" before portnumber

If this is not working, try - http://127.0.0.1:portnumnber